# Laravel - Get distinct Eloquent model names from polymorphic relationships

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I'm using polymorphic relationships in Laravel 4 and it's very useful!

If I have this:

```php
class Vehicle extends Eloquent
{
    public function machinable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Car extends Eloquent
{
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Vehicle', 'machinable');
    }
}

class Motorcycle extends Eloquent
{
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Vehicle', 'machinable');
    }
}
```

Now if I want to get all the vehicle types using what I have from the polymorphic relation, can I do that?

So if `Car` and `Motorcycle` were child classes inheriting from `Vehicle`, I'd be looking for something along the lines of "Get me children classes of Car".

How is that done?